# gcc: error trying to exec '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1': execv: Input/output error

Tags: gcc

I've searched for an attempted fix for this problem but it seems that people haven't had this problem.

When I try to compile a C program with `gcc` (Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.5.0) I get the error as said in the title but if I use `g++` it works just fine. What could be the reason for this?

(Also fairly new to Linux)

Comment: I checked it out and tried to use it but because it's mounted I can't really use `efsck` even as sudo

Comment: @TheProgrammingM16A4 You need to boot off live media so that you can check the file system unmounted. Cheers!

Comment: An Input/output error indicates that either your file system is corrupt or even worse your storage device or connection is dodgy (failing). Flagging as duplicate as as @N0rbert indicates the first step is to check your file system.